# Adding and Subtracting in Assembly issue

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

The following is an example code I am trying to compile and execute so I can have a better understanding of arithmetic in Assembly. This problem I am having is why am I getting -32641 as the value and not -36? Thank you.
**EDITED**

```
TITLE  Addition and Subtraction        (AddSub3.asm)

; Chapter 4 example. Demonstration of ADD, SUB,
; INC, DEC, and NEG instructions, and how
; they affect the CPU status flags.
; Last update: 2/1/02

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
Rval SDWORD ?
Xval SDWORD 26
Yval SDWORD 30
Zval SDWORD 40

.code
main PROC

    ; INC and DEC
    mov ax,1000h
    inc ax      ; 1001h
    dec ax      ; 1000h

    ; Expression: Rval = -Xval + (Yval - Zval)
    mov  eax,Xval
    neg  eax        ; -26
    mov  ebx,Yval
    sub  ebx,Zval       ; -10
    add  eax,ebx
    mov  Rval,eax       ; -36

    ; Zero flag example:
    mov cx,1
    sub cx,1        ; ZF = 1
    mov ax,0FFFFh
    inc ax      ; ZF = 1

    ; Sign flag example:
    mov cx,0
    sub cx,1        ; SF = 1
    mov ax,7FFFh
    add ax,2        ; SF = 1

    ; Carry flag example:
    mov al,0FFh
    add al,1        ; CF = 1,  AL = 00

    ; Overflow flag example:
    mov  al,+127
    add  al,1       ; OF = 1
    mov  al,-128
    sub  al,1       ; OF = 1

    call writeint
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: You’re printing the result out as an unsigned value, and you want signed.

Comment: 32-bit processes usually have their stack at the top of memory.  `0xffff807f` is maybe a stack address.

Comment: @Lorehead: That was my first thought, but `4294934655 - 2^32 = -32641`, so that's obviously not the only problem.

Comment: @Lorehead oh thank you! What will be the syntax for calling negative value? Thank you so much.

Comment: Read the docs for the Irvine32 library you're using: http://my.ece.msstate.edu/faculty/janem/ECE3724/S03/Webpages/libraries/irvine32_library.htm.  Pick the right `write...` function.

Comment: @Gordon_sung That seems to be in Irvine32.inc.  You almost certainly will want to `push` the value you mean to print or move it into a particular register right before you make the call.  Check the documentation, or ask your instructor if there is none.

Comment: I'm missing something. You compute a value in _EAX_ and then destroy part of _EAX_ before calling WriteDec.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes Thank you!! Unfortunately, I still result in a relatively large negative number of -32641.

Comment: @PeterCordes : This is a better link. http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/

Comment: Why is this "NASM" tagged? It wouldn't compile with NASM (it's MASM (TASM?) syntax). And if it would compile, it would compile in unexpected way, as `mov ebx,Yval` in NASM would assign label address to the ebx, for referencing memory content NASM requires the `[Yval]` notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first google hit for `Irvine32 writedec` tells you it takes an unsigned arg, and that `WriteInt` takes a signed 32-bit argument.

---

Since these functions print the full 32-bit eax register, this means you need your number sign-extended into the full eax.

The value you print is 0xffff807f (in hex).  That's `4294934655 - 2^32 = -32641` interpreted as a signed integer (2's complement, google it).

Irvine32 functions take their first arg in eax, IIRC.

You run several instructions that modify AX, and then that modify AL, after having a small negative integer in eax, so the upper 16 bits are 0xffff.  I didn't work through the details of what your later instructions do to the low 2 bytes, and then 1 byte of eax, but it doesn't look very sane.

**I'm assuming you didn't realize that AX and AL are subsets of EAX, or that writing them just leaves the rest of EAX unmodified.**

See the [irvine32](/questions/tagged/irvine32) for more info about it.  Also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links that will help correct other basic misunderstandings before they cause you problems. :)

Comment: This...is very new to me lol. Thank you. I have to keep reading more about it because I am rather new to Assembly.

Comment: The book documentation at the link in my comment and the one in the irvine32 tag is better because it actually tells you what the parameters are.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: that's a good point.  My main point was to point out how important, useful, and effective it is to use google to (try to) solve (some of) your problems, not that the first google hit is actually the most useful reference.

Comment: Yeah but you make it a big point to point out the wiki tags yet you excluded the obvious *irvine32* tag. Your answer suggests that you recall WriteDec parameter is in _EAX_. If you use the information on our own wiki tag for irvine32 you don't need to guess because the link the tag provides is far more complete and would eliminate the guess work.

Comment: I apologize but I am still rather confused. Why is the value still equal to -32641  and not -36? Thank you

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I didn't write the irvine32 tag wiki.  I didn't know a useful one existed, although in hindsight I should have looked!  Sorry for my low-effort answer, I'm not particularly interested in Irvine32 and mostly just wanted to answer the clobbering low bytes of EAX part.  If you'd like to edit this, or copy any of it into your own answer, that would be great.

Comment: @gordonsung: Because you clobbered the low bytes of EAX by messing with AX and AL.

Comment: @gordonsung Originally you had -36 in _EAX_ (0xFFFFFFDC). You then did `mov ax,0FFFFh` `inc ax` which puts 0 in _AX_. _AX_ is the lower 16-bits of _EAX_. _EAX_ now contains 0xFFFF0000. You then do `mov ax,7FFFh` `add ax,2` which puts 0x8001 into _AX_ so _EAX_ = 0xFFFF8001. You then do `mov al,0FFh` `add al,1` which puts 0 into _AL_. _AL_ is the lower 8 bits of _EAX_ so _EAX_ is 0xFFFF8000 once again. `mov  al,+127` `add  al,1` puts 0x80 into _AL_. _EAX_ is now 0xFFFF8080. You do `mov  al,-128` `sub  al,1` which puts 0x7F in _AL_. _EAX_ is now 0xFFFF807F = -32641 signed decimal.

Comment: @gordonsung `writeint` then writes the signed 32-bit value in EAX (0xFFFF807F) and you get your result displayed as -32641 which is what 0xFFFF807F is. Maybe you intended to do `call writeint` right after `mov  Rval,eax ` . _EAX_ would have still had -36 in it at that time. You may hve been unaware that AL and AX are parts of EAX and didn't realize that your original -36 was being overwritten.